# Atomic update in SQL with two queries

Tags: sql, multithreading, transactions, isolation-level

Assume that I want to do atomic update for a column with two queries:

1. `SELECT num FROM table WHERE id = ?`
   Put `num` inside variable `x`
2. `UPDATE table SET num = x + 1 WHERE id = ?`

And I make these two queries inside a transaction with isolation level: repeatable read.

Is it possible to have a deadlock situation?
Let's say there are two transactions running.

`T1` reads the value num and acquires the share lock on this row

`T2` reads the value num and acquires the share lock on this row

`T1` now wants to get the exclusive lock to write but cannot because `T2` holds a share lock

`T2` now wants to get the exclusive lock to write but cannot because `T1` holds a share lock

We have deadlock here.
But I tried in the code with Spring data JPA, there is no deadlock. Instead I have race condition and the final incremented value is less than what is expected. If I move to isolation level serializable, then I will have deadlock, and there is no race condition. The final increment value is good.

I thought serializable only deals with the range lock. ***Why does the deadlock happen in serializable isolation level and not repeatable read?*** with the two queries above.

PS: Don't tell me to user just one single UPDATE statement, I am trying to learn how to manual do atomic update with two statement and learn more about transaction here.